# ReferenceError: json is not defined when AJAX call the server method

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, json, ajax

I want to call the server method through the AJAX call. But when I am click the button and call the AJAX function at that time it shows an error.

Here is my code

```
<input type="button" id="btn_findsubmit" value="Edit" class="button" />

$(document).on("click", "#btn_findsubmit", function (e) {
    var c = $find("<%=cmbobx_search.ClientID %>");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "schoolregistration.aspx/GetSchoolName",
        data: json.stringify({ schoolname: c.get_textboxcontrol().value }),
        contenttype: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        datatype: "json",
        success: OnSuccessGetSchoolName,
        failure: function () {
            alert("error! try again...");
        }
    });
});
```

[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod]

```
public static string GetSchoolName(string schoolName){
   //Here is the code
}
```

Now when I click the button at that time JavaScript button click event is working but the ajax method do not calling the server method GetSchoolName (I know by doing debug mode).

And throws a error that:

> ReferenceError: json is not defined

Comment: `json.stringify` need to be `JSON.stringify`

Comment: you want `JSON.stringify()` capital letters

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it looks like either a typographical error, or a rather localised question that may have been abandoned without an answer.

Answer (score 5):

It should be `JSON.stringify`, not `json.stringify`

Comment: probly best as a comment

Comment: @DelightedD0D But what if that's an answer?

Comment: @bugwheels94 it is the "answer" but this is is simple typographical error. Generally, we'd just comment the answer and close the question as it has no future value

Comment: @DelightedD0D  i agreed with you.But every-one doing this (answer any-how). Only some people follow what you said.So leave it.

Comment: @michelle if I am doing the JSON.stringify then it coming other error i.e. "TypeError: c.get_textboxcontrol is not a function". Now whats going wrong???

Comment: Is there any one to know the answer?

Comment: @s.k.Soni are you sure you're grabbing the right element? try logging `c` to check what the `$find` returned

Comment: yes....I am alert the "var c = $find("<%=cmbobx_search.ClientID %>");" it showing me object object

Comment: @s.k.Soni Try printing out the jquery object in your dev console to see exactly what the $find returned, you should be able to see the element and the methods on it when you log the object.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <input type="button" id="btn_findsubmit" value="Edit" class="button" />

<script>

    $(document).on("click", "#btn_findsubmit", function (e) {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Default.aspx/GetSchoolName",
            data: JSON.stringify({ schoolName: "school name" }),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            datatype: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data.d);
            },
            failure: function () {
                alert("error! try again...");
            }
        });
    });

</script>


 [WebMethod]
 public static string GetSchoolName(string schoolName)
  {
     //Here is the code
     return "success";
  }
```

first of all it must be `JSON.stringify` not `json.stringify`, second it must be `contentType` not `contenttype` third the name of parameters in `[WebMethod]` must be same as in your ajax data.
in this case `schoolName` not `schoolname`.
hope it help you.